# Application Insights - How to SET the OperationId

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to SET/Inform the OperationID that will be mapped to Application Insights from the front end? perhaps I can send the desired operationID in a special header or something to the backend?

Comment: What is your application backend platform? Application Insights supports operation id tracking from Correlation Header in http header. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation

Comment: A concrete detailed answer depends on the backend platform you have (Java/Python/Node/asp.net core etc). The link I shared above talks about the concept first and then has examples for almost all supported platforms.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT today we have asp.net core 3.1 as our backend

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT  So, if my front-end set the `traceparent` header to "12345" the operation_id on app insights telemetry will be "12345" also?

Comment: yes, posted as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT - Is there an example for Python for Azure Functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Application Insights supports [W3C distributed tracing](https://w3c.github.io/trace-context/) standard as a first class citizen. If the below headers are present in the http request, SDK automatically takes care of setting the operation id throughout the context.

- **traceparent**: Carries the globally unique operation ID and unique identifier of the call.
- **tracestate** (optional, just in case you need) : Carries system-specific tracing context.

Since you mentioned your backend is asp.net core, starting with [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore) nuget version 2.8.0, no configuration is needed. For more details, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#enable-w3c-distributed-tracing-support-for-aspnet-core-apps